# How to import env variables in hue oozie workflow manager?

Tags: oozie, hue

I'm trying to import workflow in HUE oozie workflow editor. but Section like this

```
<env-var>HDFS_DIR=${HOME_DIR}</env-var>
<env-var>TARGET_TABLE=${SOURCE_TABLE}</env-var>
<env-var>SOURCE_DATABASE=${SOURCE_DATABASE}</env-var>
```

didn't want to import.  How can i fix it ?

Comment: Is `HOME_DIR` defined in job properties file?

Comment: no. I import only workflow.xml

Comment: Hue does not import all the fields currently. Which action is that?

Comment: i'm using Shell Action